# How to implement java Arraycopy in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, arrays

The definition of Java's `arraycopy` is here:
[Java arraycopy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

My Java code is below:

```
public byte[] getRawData() {
    byte[] raw = new byte[value.length + 4];
    //little endian defined by fido spec
    raw[0] = (byte) (tag);
    raw[1] = (byte) (tag>>8);
    raw[2] = (byte) (len);
    raw[3] = (byte) (len>>8);
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, raw, 4, value.length);
    return raw;
}
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
public func getRawData() -> [UInt8] {
    var raw = [UInt8(value.count + 4)]
    raw[0] = UInt8(tag)
    raw[1] = UInt8(tag>>8)
    raw[2] = UInt8(len)
    raw[3] = UInt8(len>>8)
    // The place the put swift arraycopy
    return raw

}
```

There is no similar function to `arraycopy` in Swift. How can I properly reimplement this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use Swift's `slice` to achieve the same results as Java's `arraycopy`:

```
var src = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var dst = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

dst[1...4] = src[0...3]

print(dst) // [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9]
```

**Note:** This does not handle bounds checking.

Comment: Thanks!!, I think I don't recognize the arraycopy in java.